# LNK1143 error on building project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I manage to find a project on git for complex svg rendering functions ([project](https://github.com/rwinlib/rsvg)).

I tried to build this project in visual studio 2015 on 32 bit version. After including the libraries and the headers everything build as expected but when I tried to use a function from rsvg class I get an error:

[image]

I just did this for a simple test:

```
#include "rsvg.h"

std::string filePath = "E://TEXT.svg";
GError ** error = NULL;
GdkPixbuf *result = rsvg_pixbuf_from_file_at_size(filePath.c_str(), -1, -1, error);
```

My question is how can I overcome this error? I opened libharfbuzz.a with notepad++ and it seems there is no libharfbuzz_la-hb-font.o but maybe I am mistaking.

Comment: _"Rebuild the file"_:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1143  If the error persists post on the git project site asking why their build system is not working for you.

Comment: I already tried this :(. The only solution that I can think of is to rebuild libharfbuzz.a but for that I need the source code and I am unable to find it.

Comment: Why do you expect `libharfbuzz.a` to work with the MSVC linker?  This is a GCC toolchain library.

Comment: I honestly did not expected to work but it seems that if i try to build other .a files like for example libcairo.a it is working. libharfbuzz.a seems to have a problem.